# How to enable second x session on tty8 in 14.04

Tags: lightdm

how can I enable a second x session on tty8 in ubuntu 14.04?

`/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and

```
[LightDM]
seats=Seat:0, Seat:1
...
[Seat:0]
user-session=ubuntu
autologin-user

[Seat:1]
user-session=ubuntu
autologin-user=
```

is not working as this file seems to be edited replaced in 14.04.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/30-seats.conf 

 [LightDM]
 seats=Seat:0, Seat:1

 [Seat:0]
 user-session=ubuntu
 autologin-user=

 [Seat:1]
 user-session=ubuntu
 autologin-user=
```